How to confirm the structure of the UNet using its code?
I have some code defining a U-Net, and params is defined as:
line 1:model = CNN()
line 2:params = model.init(params_key, X_train[:5], training=False)
and the concrete definition of U-Net is described in the following link.
(text
I don't how to check the shape of each convolutional kernel, as well as the U-Net parameters.
I have managed to print the shape of params, but there are only many lines of arrays, which I don't quite understand. So I wonder if there is a better way to show the structure in a more visible way?
